# WinEdt command *append*

Tags: winedt

The *Edit* drop down list in WinEdt has one section with four entries: Paste, cut, copy, append.  The last three are grayed out if no text is selected.  I know what paste, cut, and copy are.  But I have not found a description of *append* and when I just try poking it nothing seems to happen.

What does this append command do?

Comment: When copying if you want to add (to what already copied to the clipboard), you select (what you want to add) and use the append command, and when you paste it, you get the original copy plus the added with append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From WinEdt help: (`Index` is an index of WinEdt macros and commands):

[image]